# how i can access to sensors of microsoft band without press any button in real time?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, microsoft-band

I'm developing an application for Windows Phone and microsoft band, I need to get information from the sensors of the band in real time without having to press a button, and I can do?

Comment: Press a button where, on the phone or on the Band?  Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: in the app, you have a button to start and finish, i dont want it, i need the measure automatically

Comment: How do you determine when measurements should start and end?

Comment: i need to measure always, since the band connect to the bluetooth of my phone app

Answer (score 1):

With a quick google search here is what I have found. Without further clarification I do not know what you are specifically looking for in terms of output from the band to a custom program on the phone.
http://developer.microsoftband.com/content/docs/microsoft%20band%20sdk.pdf
*Here's some example code for starting the accelerometer.*

```
try
{
    await bandClient.SensorManager.HeartRate.StartReadingsAsync();
}
catch(BandException ex)
{
    throw ex;
}
```

Comment: it snt of the phone, is the sensors of the microsoft band

Comment: Mea Culpa my friend. The first link is correct but as you said the second one is an SDK pdf. I will delete the second link.